# Syntax for a single-line while loop in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I am having trouble coming up with the right combination of semicolons and/or braces. I'd like to do this, but as a one-liner from the command line:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    foo
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: replace newlines with semicolons.
The same works for for loops.

Comment: @Tom: that doesn't always work. after the do, you must have the first command, not a semicolon

Answer (score 1625, accepted):

```
while true; do foo; sleep 2; done
```

By the way, if you type it as a multiline (as you are showing) at the command prompt and then call the history with arrow up, you will get it on a single line, correctly punctuated.

```
$ while true
> do
>    echo "hello"
>    sleep 2
> done
hello
hello
hello
^C
$ <arrow up> while true; do    echo "hello";    sleep 2; done
```

Comment: "if you type it as a multiline (as you are showing) at the command prompt and then call the history with arrow up, you will get it on a single line, correctly punctuated." was not true for me.

Comment: @VincentScheib, check `cmdhist` option if you are using bash?

Comment: Excellent!  Works perfectly on Mavericks (Mac OS-X 10.9) and allows me to keep a vpn running.  

Openconnect disconnects after a few hours with a bad cookie error.  So I put the openconnect command in a shell script, sudo su to become root, and use this cmd line:  


      `while true; do sh /Users/myuser/bin/vpn ; done`

Comment: Worked for me in bash. Just copy paste the script (4 lines), press enter. Press Ctrl+C to exit. Then press up arrow.

Answer (score 225):

It's also possible to use sleep command in while's condition. Making one-liner looking more clean imho.

```
while sleep 2; do echo thinking; done
```

Comment: Well this does more than just changing the syntax - it will execute the command *after* the sleep. In the previous answer, the command is executed right away. Just something to note.

Comment: @DanGordon ```while echo thinking ; do sleep 2 ; done```

Of course if the [while] command fails, the loop exits, so you would have to ```while echo thinking || true ; do sleep 2 ; done``` but then you are back to ```while true ; ...```

Answer (score 94):

Colon is always "true":

```
while :; do foo; sleep 2; done
```

Comment: why is colon always true?

Comment: @Pineapple Under the Sea:
From the bash man page: (in section SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS)

`: [arguments]`
    No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any specified redirections.  A zero exit code is returned.

Comment: this syntax is recommended as : is part of shell itself i.e. : is a shell builtin command.

Comment: @avner: recommended by whom? `true` is a builtin in `dash` and `bash` as well. And while posix requires `true` only as executable they write: "even though the shell special built-in : provides similar functionality, because *`true``* is widely used in historical scripts and *is less cryptic to novice script readers*.` ( IEEE Std 1003.1-2001). See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34677/what-is-the-difference-between-and-true)

Answer (score 47):

You can use semicolons to separate statements:

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do foo; sleep 2; done
```

Comment: I like this answer because it explains when and why ; (semicolon) is required.

Answer (score 38):

You can also make use of `until` command:

```
until ((0)); do foo; sleep 2; done
```

Note that in contrast to `while`, `until` would execute the commands inside the loop as long as the test condition has an exit status which is not zero.

---

Using a `while` loop:

```
while read i; do foo; sleep 2; done < /dev/urandom
```

---

Using a `for` loop:

```
for ((;;)); do foo; sleep 2; done
```

---

Another way using `until`:

```
until [ ]; do foo; sleep 2; done
```

Comment: The `until ((0)); do foo; sleep 2; done` does not seem to work. It continuous infinite.

Answer (score 33):

Using `while`:

```
while true; do echo 'while'; sleep 2s; done
```

Using `for` Loop:

```
for ((;;)); do echo 'forloop'; sleep 2; done
```

Using `Recursion`, (a little bit different than above, keyboard interrupt won't stop it)

```
list(){ echo 'recursion'; sleep 2; list; } && list;
```

Comment: Careful using units in `sleep`, like `sleep 1h`. In my zsh, it ignores the unit `h` and runs my command every 1 second. Do a quick `man sleep` to see what your environment's `sleep` command supports first. May save you a headache.

Answer (score 17):

A very simple infinite loop.. :)

```
while true ; do continue ; done
```

Fr your question it would be:

```
while true; do foo ; sleep 2 ; done
```

Answer (score 12):

For simple process watching use `watch` instead

Comment: `watch -n 1 "echo hi"`

Answer (score 9):

I like to use the semicolons only for the WHILE statement,
and the && operator to make the loop do more than one thing...

So I always do it like this

```
while true ; do echo Launching Spaceship into orbit && sleep 5s && /usr/bin/launch-mechanism && echo Launching in T-5 && sleep 1s && echo T-4 && sleep 1s && echo T-3 && sleep 1s && echo T-2 && sleep 1s && echo T-1 && sleep 1s && echo liftoff ; done
```

Comment: Well, the use of `&&` in the loop is the same as any other time really isn't it. Do you need the second thing to happen only if the first happens, then use `&&` else `;` suffices. Really, you want to keep the contents of that loop short and simple, ideally just one command, so a function or a script.

Comment: Careful using units in `sleep`, like `sleep 1h`. In my zsh, it ignores the unit `h` and runs my command every 1 second. Do a quick `man sleep` to see what your environment's `sleep` command supports first. May save you a headache.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking for the correct way of running more than one thing in the 'do'

Answer (score 7):

If you want the while loop to stop after some condition, and your `foo` command returns non-zero when this condition is met then you can get the loop to break like this:

```sh
while foo; do echo 'sleeping...'; sleep 5; done;
```

For example, if the `foo` command is deleting things in batches, and it returns 1 when there is nothing left to delete.

This works well if you have a custom script that needs to run a command many times until some condition. You write the script to exit with `1` when the condition is met and exit with `0` when it should be run again.

For example, say you have a python script `batch_update.py` which updates 100 rows in a database and returns `0` if there are more to update and `1` if there are no more. The the following command will allow you to update rows 100 at a time with sleeping for 5 seconds between updates:

```sh
while batch_update.py; do echo 'sleeping...'; sleep 5; done;
```

Comment: and how would you exit?

Comment: You make the `foo` command exit with code `1` when you want the while loop to break. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 7):

You don't even need to use `do` and `done`. For infinite loops I find it more readable to use `for` with curly brackets. For example:

```
for ((;;)) { date ; sleep 1 ; }
```

This works in `bash` and `zsh`. Doesn't work in `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

If I can give two practical examples (with a bit of "emotion").

This writes the name of all files ended with ".jpg" in the folder "img":

```
for f in *; do if [ "${f#*.}" == 'jpg' ]; then echo $f; fi; done
```

This deletes them:

```
for f in *; do if [ "${f#*.}" == 'jpg' ]; then rm -r $f; fi; done
```

Just trying to contribute.

Comment: @JKnight - for these examples, wouldn't you just do **`ls -1 *.jpg`** and **`rm *.jpg`**

Comment: Both are not infinite loops and not while loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too 
WARNING: this you should not do but since the question is asking for infinite loop with no end...this is how you could do it.

```
while [[ 0 -ne 1 ]]; do echo "it's looping";   sleep 2; done
```

Comment: Why would you even do that?

Comment: because Brian Deacon which posted the question wanted like an infinte loop. It's more than one way to skin a cat that's all

Comment: Why should you not?

Answer (score 1):

You can also put that loop in the background (e.g. when you need to disconnect from a remote machine)

```sh
nohup bash -c "while true; do aws s3 sync xml s3://bucket-name/xml --profile=s3-profile-name; sleep 3600; done &"
```

Comment: I've always tried to avoid this for the (bad?) reason that your editor may not highlight the string context as program sytnax.

Answer (score 0):

in `bash 5` (or perhaps even earlier), you can also reverse the role of the `:` by running everything in the loop criteria but using `:` in the loop body instead :

```
while ( gdate +"%c ( %s.%-N )" && sleep 0.71  ) do :; done  # discards side-effects
      
while { gdate +"%c ( %s.%-N )" && sleep 0.71; } do :; done  # no sub-shell needed
```

---

```
+ gdate '+%c ( %s.%-N )'
Sun Apr 30 12:38:25 2023 ( 1682872705.498728 )
+ sleep 0.71
+ :

+ gdate '+%c ( %s.%-N )'
Sun Apr 30 12:38:26 2023 ( 1682872706.218152 )
+ sleep 0.71

...
```

---

meanwhile `zsh` is even more forgiving, and willing to loop even without the `:`

```
while; do gdate +'%c ( %s.%-N )' && sleep 0.31 ; done

Sun Apr 30 12:46:09 2023 ( 1682873169.469092 )
Sun Apr 30 12:46:09 2023 ( 1682873169.789560 )
Sun Apr 30 12:46:10 2023 ( 1682873170.105635 )
Sun Apr 30 12:46:10 2023 ( 1682873170.424766 )
```