# How to resolve the error in bash script to put load on cpu?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two scripts to put a spike on CPU .

infinite_loop.bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ] ; do
    # Force some computation even if it is useless to actually work the CPU
    echo $((13**99)) 1>/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

cpu_spike.bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Either use environment variables for NUM_CPU and DURATION, or define them here
for i in `seq ${NUM_CPU}` : do
    # Put an infinite loop on each CPU
    infinite_loop.bash &
done

# Wait DURATION seconds then stop the loops and quit
sleep ${DURATION}
killall infinite_loop.bash
```

The script was earlier working fine. BUt now the scriptis not working fine. Its giving me an error :

```
./cpu_spike.bash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `infinite_loop.bash'
./cpu_spike.bash: line 5: `    infinite_loop.bash &'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the following line:

```
for i in `seq ${NUM_CPU}` : do
```

You need to terminate the `for` using a `;`, not `:`.  Say:

```
for i in `seq ${NUM_CPU}` ; do
```

`:` is a null command.

---

Moreover, saying:

```
while [ 1 ] ; do command ; done
```

to simulate an infinite loop is *incorrect* while it actually does produce one.  You might observe that saying:

```
while [ 0 ] ; do command ; done
```

would also result in an infinite loop.  The correct way would be to say:

```
while true ; do command; done
```

or

```
while : ; do command; done
```

or

```
while ((1)); do command; done
```

For other variations of producing an infinite loop, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18429169/2235132) answer.

Comment: I just want to put a load on cpu using some script that goes in an infinite loop

Comment: Its giving me an error : `seq: missing operand
Try `seq --help' for more information.
^C`

Comment: @user3086014 You would get this error if you haven't set the variable `NUM_CPU`.

Comment: @user3086014 Before any line using the variable `NUM_CPU`, set it to value.  For example, saying `NUM_CPU=4` would set the value to 4.

Comment: but earlier the script was working fine without setting the value for CPU

Comment: @user3086014 Maybe you had set the variable in your shell?

Comment: No i havnt set the variable anywhere