# Bash script: syntax error near unexpected token?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

```
function nvis()
{
    while true; do
    nvidia-smi
    sleep $1 
    done
}
```

I'm trying to use it like:

```
nvis 2
```

and I get an error like:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
```

Sorry if this is obvious; I am kind of stumped.

Comment: this is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289026/syntax-for-a-single-line-bash-infinite-while-loop, but they don't take a command line argument, which seems to be causing my problem

Comment: Please write a title that summarizes the specific problem. For example: Why is that bash function doesn't expect parameters ? Or something like that.

Comment: Is that what is going on?  It doesn't expect parameters for some reason?  I've used similar syntax in other bash functions with no problem.... $1 is the first command line argument, no?  I changed the title, but I'm not sure what the most descriptive thing would be.

Comment: your function is perfectly fine.
pls post the entire script.

Comment: Try http://www.shellcheck.net/ with your script.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Changing the function name fixed it.  The whole script is... my .bashrc file, so I won't put it here.  It could also have something to do with my lab's configuration which I also load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your information, the error is not reproducible. This works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

function nvis()
{
  while true; do
    echo nvidia-smi
    sleep $1 
  done
}

nvis 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I also tried your code - works fine.  I will guess that your file contains 'hidden' control codes.  Try:

```
cat -v yourfile  # OR
cat -vE yourfile
```

See any special codes? - remove them

Also, try:

```
bash -nv yourfile
```

:)