# How i can make auto restart in linux sh

Tags: c#, linux, bash, batch-file, mono

I need run c# apps (in console mode and background) on machine with Linux. I don't know how to make script like .bat in Windows (i don't use too much Linux, excepting Android OS):

```
@echo off
:work
start /wait app.exe
goto work
```

I have installed mono, and my app is working. But i need automatically restart when it crashed.

In future i need to run more than one c# app using mono on this machine.

Comment: `while true; do app; done` ?

Comment: This was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289026/syntax-for-a-single-line-bash-infinite-while-loop

Comment: Linux and batch files do not mix.