# Syntax for a Bash single-line while loop with condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I gone through [single line inifinite while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289026/syntax-for-a-single-line-bash-infinite-while-loop) in bash, and trying to add a single line while loop with condition. Below I have mentioned my command, which gives unexpected result (It is suppose to stop after 2 iterations, but it never stops. And also it considers variable I as executable).

Command:

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt 2 ]; do echo "hi"; sleep 1; i = $i + 1; done
```

Output:

```
hi
The program 'i' is currently not installed. To run 'i' please ....
hi 
The program 'i' is currently not installed. To run 'i' please ....
hi 
The program 'i' is currently not installed. To run 'i' please ....
...
...
```

Note: I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If you are doing a loop over particular values of `i`, you don't want a while loop.  You want: `for((i=0;i<2;i++)); do ... ; done`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bash` is particular about spaces in variable assignments. The shell has interpreted `i = $i + 1` as a command `i` and the rest of them as arguments to `i`, that is why you see the errors is saying `i` is not installed.

In `bash` just use the arithmetic operator (See [Arithmetic Expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression)),

```
i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 2 ]; do echo "hi"; sleep 1; ((i++)); done
```

You could use the arithmetic expression in the loop context also

```
while((i++ < 2)); do echo hi; sleep 1; done
```

POSIX-ly

```
i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 2 ]; do echo "hi"; sleep 1; i=$((i+1)); done
```

POSIX shell supports `$(( ))` to be used in a math context, meaning a context where the syntax and semantics of C's integer arithmetic are used.

Answer (score 2):

`i=0; while [ $i -lt 2 ]; do echo "hi"; sleep 1; i=$(($i + 1)); done`