# Best way to start X number of the same Docker Containers

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker container that contains a server.

I want to spin up multiple instances of this container that are all listening on a different port. I know I can issue multiple `docker run` commands which works fine for small numbers, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered larger-scale container orchestrators (Docker Swarm, Kubernetes, Nomad, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to achieve this.

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt no_of_times ]; do docker run -d -p 80 <image_id>; sleep 1; ((i++)); done
```

Looking forward to an even better solution.

Got this one-liner from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289029/9025542)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using [docker-compose scale](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) scale functionality.

Basically defining a single [service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference) and scaling it.

For instance, defining a **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  your-service:
    image: "your-image"
  ports:
    - "<port to expose>"
```

Then when you want to start several instances execute:

```
docker-compose up --scale your-service=X
```

You could also take a look to [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) mode, which allows you to define services using command line